# Property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance in Laravel 8 and Livewire 2.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

My `users` can create multiple `usercar`'s when selecting from a database of `car`'s.  I need to grab the selected `car` values, but when I `dd` the values, I get a `Property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.` error.  `wire:model="car_id"` is the select input value used in the code below.

**AddUserCar.php**

```
...
class AddUserCar extends Component
{
    public $showAnotherModel = false;

    // Steps
    public $totalSteps = 8;
    public $step = 1;
    // User
    public $super;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;
    public $email;
    public $status = 1;
    public $role = 'Driver';
    // Usercar
    public $car_id;
    public $calc_date;
    public $year;
    public $model;
    // Form Function
    public $car_year;

    //public $cars;
    //public $modelId;

    ...

    public function moveAhead()
    {

        if($this->step == 1) {
            $newCar = Car::where('id', '=', $this->car_id)->get();
            dd($newCar->id); // This is where I get error

            $this->usercarCreated = Usercar::create([
                'year' => $newCar->start_year,
                'model' => $newCar->model,

                'car_id' => $this->car_id,
                'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                'tenant_id' => Auth::user()->tenant_id,
                'calc_date' => now()->format('m-d-Y'),
            ]);

            $this->resetErrorBag();
            $this->resetValidation();
        }

        ...

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.add-user-car',
        ['pageTitle' => 'Add Driver Car']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`->get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-all-rows-from-a-table) to retrieving all rows from a table :

```
$cars = Car::where('id', '=', $this->car_id)->get();

foreach($cars as $car){
    echo $car->id;
}

// ERROR, because $cars isn't a single row
dd($cars->id);
```

Use [`->first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table) to retrieving a single row / column from a table.

```
$car = Car::where('id', '=', $this->car_id)->first();
// or 
$car = Car::find($this->car_id);

// WORK
dd($car->id);
```

Comment: went with `$car = Car::find($this->car_id);` because it was cleaner.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$newCar = Car::where('id', '=', $this->car_id)->get();
```

This statement does not find any data, so `$newcar` is empty, and an empty object has no ID